# mysql apply regexp_replace for whole column/multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I Have column `exe_production` inside `users_acts` table with data like `blah blah blah 10.10.2020 (any date) blah blah.

I need to order this column by date.

My steps:

1. Get date from string by next query:

   ```
   SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE((SELECT exe_production FROM users_acts LIMIT 1), '[^[0-9]{2}[.]{1}[0-9]{2}[.]{1}[0-9]{4}]', '');
   ```
2. Convert all results strings to date by `DATE_FORMAT` statement.
3. Apply `ORDER BY` statement.

The problem is that I can't apply first query for multiple rows/values, only by `LIMIT 1`. How I can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea was good, but you need `STR_TO_DATE` and you need the `REGEXP_REPLACE` in the `SELECT` not around a subselect

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users_acts (exe_production varchar(100))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO users_acts VALUES ('blah blah blah 10.10.2020 (any date) blah blah')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     STR_TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(exe_production,
>             '[^[0-9]{2}[.]{1}[0-9]{2}[.]{1}[0-9]{4}]',
>             ''),'%d.%m. %Y')
> FROM
>     users_acts
> ```
>
> ```
> | STR_TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(exe_production,
>            '[^[0-9]{2}[.]{1}[0-9]{2}[.]{1}[0-9]{4}]',
>            ''),'%d.%m. %Y') |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 2020-10-10                                                                                                                     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a34613d54413863ade8e58509a28bbb2)*